# There is a way in PyTest to order collect tests by using pytest_collect_file hook?

Tags: pytest

When I run `pytest_collect_file` to collect all tests (manual/automation) this collector run first and I can't get the ID's of the automation test to remove duplicate tests.

I want to report my manual test via PyTest, so I wrote some code that get the execution status of the tests and now I'm trying to report each test with the status of the execution test via PyTest.

To do that i'm using with `pytest_collect_file` pytest function, and I collect all manual test.

The problem is that now I have all the tests of the project, the manual and the automation tests. I want to remove the automation test from the collection list to remove duplicate report. I can get the testID of the automation test if pytest collect all the automation test before I'm add the manual via `pytest_collect_file` but the problem is that this function called first.

my collector base on this code 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/nonpython.html

Comment: You can filter the collected tests in a custom impl of the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook; just go through the `items` list and remove tests from `items` that don't match certain criteria.

Comment: thanks.
as I can see you can't remove item from the items list. pytest doesn't delete them.

Comment: No, it works; you need to work with `items` reference though, no copying or reassigning. If you have any troubles, update the question with failing code example.

Comment: Thank you! it work well.